# Salesforce Critical Updates Disable Access to Non-global Controller Methods in Managed Packages

Tags: apex, critical-update

As per salesforce critical updates, (https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_apex_cruc_access_public_methods_in_packages.htm)
Is this update enforce while creating a managed packages or while accessing methods from managed packages?
Because what i know is ; you cant view the managed package code only the signature gets displayed, so how we can access the methods with just signature and secondly this update is for unlimited edition as well. I know that from prod we should not create managed package it should be always from developer edition environemt.

So what this update is actually gonna do , can you help me to understand

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what is causing the confusion. [Release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_apex_cruc_access_public_methods_in_packages.htm) states this update is to fix the bug introduced with Lightning components in managed packages:

> Prior to this update, non-global methods (that is, Apex controller methods that weren’t marked with the global access modifier) could be accessed by Lightning components outside of the package namespace.

Comment: Thank you for the post. I have read the notes already. My question - is this update says that while accessing the managed packages controller methods in a new lightning components which I will be creating needs to have a global access modifier?

Comment: The lightning components inside managed package would be able to access the public methods. Its a simple correction, with which now components outside package would be able to access packaged class marked as global and not private.